# radio button onchange/onclick event not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to get value of radio button onclick or onchange event. But it only work for first item not for other item. When I click on first radio button it alert the radio button value. But when I click on other radion button it don't alert nothing.

My code is here

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="layout" id="layout" class="ace">1
<input type="radio" value="2" name="layout" id="layout" class="ace">2
<input type="radio" value="3" name="layout" id="layout" class="ace">3
<input type="radio" value="4" name="layout" id="layout" class="ace">4
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#layout').on("click", function(e){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try avoiding duplicate `id's`(Id should be unique on a page), instead use name attribute as shown below :-

```
$('input[name="layout"]').on("click", function(e){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id) attribute should be unique on the page. You need to use `class` instead:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="layout" class="layout ace">1
<input type="radio" value="2" name="layout" class="layout ace">2
<input type="radio" value="3" name="layout" class="layout ace">3
<input type="radio" value="4" name="layout" class="layout ace">4
```

jQuery:

```
$('.layout').on("click", function(e){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id):

> The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the
>   element using getElementById.

Answer (score 1):

`id` attribute must be unique on the page. you always get the value of the first element with that id...

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
        function first()
        {
            var a = document.getElementById("opt1").value;
            alert(a);
        }
        function second()
        {
            var b=document.getElementById("opt2").value;
            alert(b);
        }
        function third()
        {
            var c=document.getElementById("opt3").value;
            alert(c);
        }
        function fourth()
        {
            var d=document.getElementById("opt4").value;
            alert(d);
        }
        </script>

            <input type="radio" value="1"  name="layout" id="opt1" class="layout ace" onclick="first()">1
            <input type="radio" value="2"  name="layout" id="opt2" class="layout ace" onclick="second()">2
            <input type="radio" value="3"  name="layout" id="opt3" class="layout ace" onclick="third()">3
            <input type="radio" value="4"  name="layout" id="opt4" class="layout ace" onclick="fourth()">4
```